# Replace every element with next greatest element (in ascending order, not replacing with -1)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Currently working on an algorithm that replaces every element with the next greatest element, but unlike some other questions here, this one is not concerned with replacing values with -1 if no such number exists, and it must be in ascending order.

Given this input: {1, 5, -3, 2, 8, 4, 7, 10, 3, 11, 2 }

Have to get this output: 1 5 5 5 8 8 8 10 10 11 11

This is what I have so far:

```
class Playground {
static void nextGreatest(int arr[])  { 
    int size = arr.length; 

    // Initialize the next greatest element 
    int max_from_right =  arr[size - 1]; 

    // Replace all other elements with the next greatest 
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) 
    { 
        // Store the current element (needed later for 
        // updating the next greatest element) 
        int temp = arr[i]; 

        // Replace current element with the next greatest 
        arr[i] = max_from_right; 

        // Update the greatest element, if needed 
        if(max_from_right < temp) { 
            max_from_right = temp;
        } 
    } 
} 

// prints the array 
static void printArray(int arr[]) 
{ 
    for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    System.out.print(arr[i]+" "); 
} 

public static void main (String[] args) {
    int arr[] = {1, 5, -3, 2, 8, 4, 7, 10, 3, 11, 2 }; 
    nextGreatest (arr); 
    printArray (arr); 

    }
}
```

And I get the following right now:

1 2 5 5 5 8 8 8 10 10 11

Thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think the DP tag is appropriate. This is greedy.

Comment: What does "next greatest element" mean, here?

Comment: Thanks for that!

Comment: What must be the output for `1,2,100,6,7`? Is it `1,2,100,100,100`?

Comment: Just to confirm, looks like we ignore the first element?

Comment: @user7 {1, 2, 100, 100, 100 }

Comment: @Always Learning yep.

Comment: @David Contrad refers to the value of the next element in the array. If it's greater than the one before it, it replaces every value after that, until another higher value is reached.

Comment: I see. BTW, you might be able to replace `printArray` with `Arrays.toString` (from `java.util`) unless the exact output format is critical.

Comment: @David Conrad You're so right, forgot about that haha. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkT. So, **the situation** of  **-1** would never come.

Comment: " and it must be in ascending order" is redundant. The result is always in ascending order.

Comment: I believe that phrase "replaces every element with the next greatest element" might denote: `{1, 5, -3, 2, 8, 4, 7, 10, 3, 11, 2 } =>{5,8,2,8.10,7,10,11,11,?,?} (righter greater)` or `{2,7,1,3,10,5...} (next greater value)`

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
int currMax = -1;
int[] input = {1, 5, -3, 2, 8, 4, 7, 10, 3, 11, 2};

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    if (input[i] > currMax){ // if we find a new max element
        currMax = input[i];
    }
    else if (input[i] < currMax){ // if value is less then max we replace it
        input[i] = currMax;
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input));
> [1, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 11, 11]
```

Comment: The question is tagged as Java

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry about the mix up! Edited to Java accordingly

Answer (score 1):

(Not sure I understand your question exactly, but based on the clarification from the comments here is my answer...)

Seems you just need to change the initial max initialization to the first element rather than the last element.

```
int currentMax =  arr[0];

for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = currentMax;
    if(currentMax < temp) {
        currentMax = temp;
    }
}
```

The solution ends up as *For each index i, what is the maximum element seen so far*.

Comment: Yikes, I see it now. Thanks so much!